# Microsoft Edge - back button on mouse not working

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse, microsoft-edge

Back button on my mouse doesn't work in Microsoft Edge. It works in IE 11, Firefox, Windows Explorer etc. just not in Edge... Is this issue of Edge or is there something wrong with my setup?

I'm using Windows 10 and Logitech MX Master Mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Edge by default does not include any add-ons or extension support. IE 11 has accelerators, and Chrome also has hardware accelerators. I believe these are what allow the mouse to navigate. Edge is Microsoft's attempt to rectify years of IE being labeled "insecure".

Some forums indicate they may concede a little on this, but there is no slated date for extension support.

http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't know such is simple thing as mouse back button needs browser extension. So that means that nobody in the world can use mouse buttons to go back in Edge?

Comment: It appears so. Mouse clicks are one thing, but mouse interoperability with browser functions requires integration between the OS and the browser. I searched all conceivable settings in/around Windows 10, mouse accessibility in Control Panel, and Edge settings. There isn't any way to link them. If Edge supported extensions, you could write one, but it doesn't... Yet. To test the idea, you can disable hardware acceleration in Chrome, restart browser, and see what you get. I'm curious.

Comment: I doubt that this has to do with browser plugins.  [This tweet from Microsoft](https://twitter.com/MSEdgeDev/status/644313048178540544) suggests that Edge _should_ support mice with back buttons.  Maybe there are certain ones it's incompatible with.

Comment: Interesting but I think the question remains. We aren't talking strictly about plugins here, but also extensions and even simple browser settings. I was curious about the hardware acceleration setting specifically. If there is no shortcut capability, what allows the mouse buttons to work with the browser?

Comment: This has nothing to do with extension support.  Applications receive messages such WM_APPCOMMAND with APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_FORWARD or APPCOMMAND_BROWSER_BACKWARD.  Applications can also process Virtual Keycodes (VK) that represent commands.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge as of this writing, May 2017, supports back and forward buttons that are on mouse input devices and specialty buttons on some keyboards.